# What is this hole in my basement floor and how do I repair it?

Tags: basement

The house was built in 1935 and is located in Pittsburgh, PA USA. The basement floor is concrete. There's no sump pump or any other kind of hole or hookup in the basement.

The hole is along the middle of the back wall, far from any of the other floor drains or the drain stack.

The rectangular looking channel in the middle of the hole appears (and feels) like it goes left and right some way under the floor. Is this some kind of interior drain?

If so, how do I properly repair the hole without interfering with drainage

[image: basement floor]

Comment: Is there any slope around it? Does it look broken out or formed?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of homebrew construction was still going on back then. I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a makeshift floor drain for occasional use, say in the case of plumbing problems or heavy rain.

It's also possible that it's just a sinkhole from poorly mixed concrete and inadequate substrate compaction.

If the basement has been dry for a number of years, just patch it up with masonry of some sort (whatever's on hand). If you're not sure, consider installing a proper drain grate to clean it up aesthetically but leave it functional.

Comment: It’s pretty far away from the main floor drains (it’s against a back wall). It’s really shaping up to be an interior drain. I’m not sure how to cover that rectangular channel so I can patch the floor.

Comment: I'm not sure what rectangular channel you're referring to. Does the photo show it?

Comment: Let me markup the photo and repost tomorrow. I guess I’m used to staring at this thing 

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from the picture. If this is a floor drain that goes into your main sewer pipe, or perhaps a hole dug at one time to clear a blockage in the sewer pipe, then filling it with concrete would be a **very bad thing**. If you are 100% certain it is just a hole but with no output down below (if done right like the floor drain in my house, there would actually be a trap, a pain to snake through, but keeps sewer gas from going out the hole) and no connection to any pipes, then you can fill it. Otherwise, I would figure out a way to cover it - including even a smooth coating on top to match your floor - without actually filling it in, just to avoid the small but real possibility of turning an unsightly hole in the floor into a complete sewer blockage.

Comment: Yeah, it’s definitely appearing like an interior drain. I guess I’m not sure how to cover it so that I can patch it.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean - How to cover it for a patch depends somewhat on how deep it is. It looks like there is one part that is very deep - i.e., possibly a real drain, which you don't want to actually fill in, and another section around it that is a little shallower than the rest of the floor, but hard to tell. Can you provide a picture showing a larger area?